# Odoo 11 - pull fields values from other models

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have added a custom field (many2one) in crm.lead form and a custom class for that

Here is my code (I am using odoo 11):

> models.py

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api

# Add fields to Leads
class Leads_events(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    venue = fields.Many2one('crm.lead.venue',String="Venue")
    venue_city = fields.Char(String="City")
    venue_country = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="Country")

# Create venue class
class Leads_venue(models.Model):
    _name = 'crm.lead.venue'

    name = fields.Char(string="Venue name")
    city = fields.Char(string="City")
    country = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="Country")
    address = fields.Text(string="Address")
    website = fields.Char(string="Website")
    phone = fields.Char(string="Phone")
    fax = fields.Char(string="Fax")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
```

> views.xml

```xml
<record id="crm_lead_venue_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.venue.form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead.venue</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Venues">
                <group>
                    <group>
                      <field name="name"/>
                      <field name="country"/>
                      <field name="city"/>
                      <field name="address"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                      <field name="phone"/>
                      <field name="fax"/>
                      <field name="website"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                      <field name="notes" />
                    </group>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

<record id="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor_events" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm_case_form_view_oppor_events</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">    
        <xpath expr="//notebook" position="before">
            <group string="Venue">
                <field name="venue"/>
                <field name="event_city" string="City"/>
                <field name="event_country"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

This works fine. Now what I am trying to pull is the city and country from crm.lead.venue selected record to crm.lead 'venue_city' and 'venue_country' fields.

I looked at onchange function but I cannot find how to make it work...

I've tried this following another post I read but it is not working

```py
@api.onchange('venue')
def onchange_venue(self):
    if self.venue:
        self.event_city = self.venue.city
        self.event_country = self.venue.country
```

Is there anywhere I can find a documentation or help more complete on this ? The official documentation is not very precise on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onchange method works when the user change the field in the view, and I cant see the field on your view, so the method would be never be called. You should add "venue" field to the form and test it again.

**Edit**

Have you seen that it is not event_city but venue_city? The onchange should be on leads_events. Did you test that onchange is executed and has no value? Or it doesnt even execute the function ?

```
@api.onchange('venue')
def onchange_venue(self):
    if self.venue:
        self.venue_city = self.venue.city
        self.venue_country = self.venue.country
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to paste the code for the Opportunity (crm.lead) view. Initial post modified.

Comment: That's it, the onchange was not on the leads_events... Thanks a lot !!